# Is it bad practice to use the positive/rising edge of a "non-clock" signal?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog, hdl

*Situation*:

Before a `data ready` signal can go high it must wait for a `data valid` signal to go high. Once `data ready` goes high, `data ready` must remain high until a separate process is complete which should reset `data ready` to low and again `data ready` should wait for `data valid` to go high and so forth.

*FPGA*: **xc7s25**csga324-1, Spartan-7 S25, speed grade -1,
[Switching Characteristics](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds189-spartan-7-data-sheet.pdf)

Timing diagram of hypothetical situation for a 3-bit sample:

[image]

*Problem*:

`data valid` only goes high for one clock cycle and so it would be convenient for the `data ready` to wait for the *positive/rising edge* of `data valid`.

*Question*:

Will programming the `data ready` signal to trigger on the positive/rising edge of `data valid` cause issues in implementation since `data valid` is not a clock?

Comment: Draw the timing diagram please.

Comment: in hobbyist electronic, you can have appoximative timings but it is always a risk to get a bad sequence each X% of use. Please give a real example and-or a datagram or time-diagram as example

Comment: Does a usual D-flipflop with Reset  (e.g. type 1G175) realize your function? If so, you have your answer. If the 175 is a real part that people use, its function is obviously not a "bad practise"

Comment: It sounds like you only need RS FF. data_valid sets, and separate_process resets.

Comment: Well, in RTL, if you do something on `datavalid`  rising edge, then Synthesiser considers/treats it as a clock signal. If FPGA, Synthesisers usually won't allow ANY USER LOGIC on `datavalid` path anymore, because it is literally a clock signal now.

Comment: It is more convenient to sample `datavalid` as high on rising edge of clock.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54819460/systemverilog-comparing-two-ways-to-wait-signal-1-clock-iff-condition-2/54820439#54820439

Comment: I'm adding a timing diagram. Hold on guys...

Comment: I added a timing diagram for you all

Comment: @MituRaj Yeah, I think I will do that instead. I was just curious what sort of impact this would have if I chose to sample on something not technically a clock in my HDL but will end up being synthesized as a clock. Such as what sort of problems could result and why

Comment: If your intention is to use data_ready as a back pressure signal, perhaps it would be better to redefine its meaning. Have a look at the AXI handshake for example, which places no restrictions on VALID and READY, and thus avoids a number of problems, including deadlock. All handshake state is computed prior to the rising edge of the clock, then sampled.

Comment: Do you have a minimum hold time spec for the datavalid signal? Is it longer than one full clock cycle?

Comment: I think your hand-shaking mechanism is not a good one in terms of performance. As hacktastical said, you may want to look at AXI specs to see how a simple `datavalid` `ready` handshaking can be done. Quite straight forward, and bonus -- can be directly integrated with typical FIFOs.

Comment: @Hearth I'm trying to interpret the CLB switching characteristics but it would appear that no, the minimum hold time is definitely not longer than one full clock cycle

Comment: If this is for a specific chip, please _edit your question_ to include the chip's manufacturer and part number, and if possible provide a link to the data sheet.

Comment: @MituRaj OK. I've used AXI-Streaming before... I guess I can review it and use it again. Maybe my OP is too broad. I can delete it if people want...

Comment: @TimWescott done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If whatever you're interfacing to acts per the drawing, then AND data_ready and data_valid together, and sample at the falling edge of the clock.  Then hold that state and do whatever you do with the incoming data bits until data_valid goes low, and stop.

Comment: That is an interesting idea! I'll try this and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in a HDL implementation you want all register clocks (and by implication if rising_edge(xxx) and the like) to refer to actual clock signals.
You can play it the other way, but it is not generally a great idea, mostly because it makes timing analysis hard.

Were I writing this, it would be a set reset latch set by data valid and reset once the three bits have been clocked in. The output from the SR latch is then data ready, and that is the only bit of asyncronous logic.

All the rest can be `if rising_edge (clk) and data_ready then` which will synthesise to clocked registers with clock enable inputs, which the timing analysis knows how to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. I ended up also implementing this using as an SR latch like you suggested and that has worked too